# Sending email to record owners in a report

Tags: email, reporting, email-alert

I have a report that contains the top 20 opportunities for a certain industry.  Is there a way to automatically send an email to those specific opportunity owners on a monthly basis?  These opportunity owners will change month to month.

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to do this out of the box. Choose an [automation technique](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_whichtool) and implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use BatchApex script for sending email. This logic needs to be custom build based on the business conditions.

schedule to run every month.

**Refer for Scheduling logic:**
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IEIhQAO